# input-group-addon with bootstrap-select

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

I tried to use *Label 2* with *bootstrap-select*, but it looks different to the *bootstrap* (*Label 1*) one. How is it possible to get the two labels in the code below look the same?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../docs-assets/ico/favicon.png">

    <title>Test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/non-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Labe 1</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="snpid" placeholder="Test">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">GO!</button>
          </span>
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->  
    <div>    
    <BR/>
    <HR>

  <div class="container">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Label 2</span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select id="lunch" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" title="Please select a lunch ...">
          <option>Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
          <option>Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
          <option>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
          <option>Baby Back Ribs</option>
          <option>A really really long option made to illustrate an issue with the live search in an inline form</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div>  

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: According to http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups you should
"Avoid using <select> elements here as they cannot be fully styled in WebKit browsers".

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From Bootstrap [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups):

> Extend form controls by adding text or buttons before, after, or on both sides of any text-based `<input>`. Use `.input-group` with an `.input-group-addon` or `.input-group-btn` to prepend or append elements to a single `.form-control`.

You need to wrap the `select` and `.input-group-addon` in a `.input-group`:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Label 2</span>
  <select id="lunch" class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" title="Please select a lunch ...">
    <option>Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
    <option>Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
    <option>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
    <option>Baby Back Ribs</option>
    <option>A really really long option made to illustrate an issue with the live search in an inline form</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Check it out:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Labe 1</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="snpid" placeholder="Test">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">GO!</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <hr>
  <div class="container">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Label 2</span>
        <select id="lunch" class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" title="Please select a lunch ...">
          <option>Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
          <option>Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
          <option>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
          <option>Baby Back Ribs</option>
          <option>A really really long option made to illustrate an issue with the live search in an inline form</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In my browser the select is rounded, which makes it not to "fit" in the label. Does this happens to you too?

Comment: In my browser there is standard select, and the question is about bootstrap-select, add-on to Bootstrap!

Answer (score 19):

I've modified caeth's solution with additional CSS to ensure the select button is rounded at their respective corners.

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Label</span>
        <select id="lunch" class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" title="Please select a lunch ...">
            <option>Hot Dog, Fries, and a Soda</option>
            <option>Burger, Shake, and a Smile</option>
            <option>Sugar, Spice, and all things nice</option>
            <option>Baby Back Ribs</option>
            <option>A really really long option made to illustrate an issue with the live search in an inline form</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.input-group > .input-group-btn:last-child > .selectpicker {
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.input-group > .input-group-btn:first-child > .selectpicker {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/xr4uofje/130/

Answer (score 0):

I've just found an easy way to include add-ons with select (no bootstrap-select). This answer might not be strictly related to the bootstrap-select question, but might be helpful for someone landing here looking for this answer (as I did). I just move the select under the add-on, with margin:-4px, and add 4 pixels to the width like this

```
.input-group select.form-control {
    margin-left: -4px;
    width: calc(100% + 4px);
}
```

and then I set a relative position and z-index to the add-on, like this:

```
.input-group .input-group-addon {
    z-index: 5;
    position: relative;
}
```

I hope this helps